# Calculate the median of a billion numbers

Tags: algorithm, distributed-computing

If you have one billion numbers and one hundred computers, what is the best way to locate the median of these numbers?

One solution which I have is:

- Split the set equally among the computers.
- Sort them.
- Find the medians for each set.
- Sort the sets on medians.
- Merge two sets at a time from the lowest to the highest median.

If we have `m1 < m2 < m3 ...` then first merge `Set1` and `Set2` and in the resulting set we can discard all the numbers lower than the median of `Set12` (merged). So at any point of time we have equal sized sets. By the way this cannot be done in a parallel manner. Any ideas?

Comment: are the billion numbers sorted?

Comment: @John Boker: actually the problem consists of two subproblems: 1) sort the list and 2) get element with index 5'000'000'000. I hardly believe that numbers are sorted.

Comment: Is this homework, an interview question, or just curiosity?

Comment: This is an interview question found on a site

Comment: @Roman: the problem need not consist of the two subproblems you describe, e.g. quickselect. But quickselect doesn't parallelize, at least not trivially. And of course you're right that if the numbers are pre-sorted it's a pretty pointless question.

Comment: @fmsf: I don't think any English-speaking country uses the long billion *in English* for any official purposes. For instance here in the UK, we stopped using it in 1974. I would consider the use of "billion" to mean a million million, *in the English language* to be a perverse trick question, not a "real billion" at all. Of course in French it would be a totally different matter, but the question isn't in French.

Comment: @steve: I on the other hand would imediatly visualise a billion as being one "million million" as you said. I'm european so i guess it does make sense

Comment: Yes, if I was speaking French (which I haven't done for a very long time, and badly even then), or any other European language I would no doubt make the reverse mistake all the time, saying "billion" for "milliard". So on second thoughts it's not necessarily a trick to use "billion" for "million million" in English, it might just be a hard-to-avoid translation error. My reaction would be more suitable directed to English speakers trying to return to the days when we used "proper" billions and Britannia ruled the waves ;-)

Comment: You don't need to sort!
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm#Linear_general_selection_algorithm_-_.22Median_of_Medians_algorithm.22

Comment: @anony: Nice question! Can you share the site where you found the question?

Comment: 1 billion of numbers is only a few gigabytes of data, you don't need multiple PCs nor complex algorithms to solve this task. Don't overcomplicate.

Comment: obligatory questions: 1) where are the numbers stored? 2) define "best way"

Comment: Reminds me of a Google interview question...

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1914/to-find-the-median-of-an-unsorted-array

Comment: if you just want to "locate" it, use sampling and one computer...

Comment: what type of numbers, it makes a difference if these just integers or a flaying numbers .. etc.

Comment: Have you considered using GPU computing? GPUs are exceptionally good at doing what you want.

Comment: Given multiple machines that can communicate with a latency low compared to the expected completion time, this seems to cry for an on-line algorithm: distribute the data (a subject to ponder in its own right: imagine the input being "almost ordered"), exchange current estimates of (per subset/machine) median every now and then (would probably go for a Fibonacci sequence for the hell of it), just count outliers at the risk of having to start over (with more knowledge about value distribution).

Comment: @Jean-LucNacifCoelho I don't think that's true. This problem has incredibly low compute density. GPUs are good at the opposite kind of task.

Comment: @fmsf If it was "continental" billions (10^12), then it would be awkward to store them (assuming int32 numers, that would be a 4TB file just for the numbers). Anyway, being in the realm of theoretical questions, this question should be "How to find the median of a ludicrous amount of items?(disregarding low level details)"

Comment: @KonradRudolph you are right. I forgot median calculation had high data dependency. My bad.

Answer (score 54):

Ah, my brain has just kicked into gear, I have a sensible suggestion now. Probably too late if this had been an interview, but never mind:

Machine 1 shall be called the "control machine", and for the sake of argument either it starts with all the data, and sends it in equal parcels to the other 99 machines, or else the data starts evenly distributed between the machines, and it sends 1/99 of its data to each of the others. The partitions do not have to be equal, just close.

Each other machine sorts its data, and does so in a way which favours finding the lower values first. So for example a quicksort, always sorting the lower part of the partition first[*]. It writes its data back to the control machine in increasing order as soon as it can (using asynchronous IO so as to continue sorting, and probably with Nagle on: experiment a bit).

The control machine performs a 99-way merge on the data as it arrives, but discards the merged data, just keeping count of the number of values it has seen. It calculates the median as the mean of the 1/2 billionth and 1/2 billion plus oneth values.

This suffers from the "slowest in the herd" problem. The algorithm cannot complete until every value less than the median has been sent by a sorting machine. There's a reasonable chance that one such value will be quite high within its parcel of data. So once the initial partitioning of the data is complete, estimated running time is the combination of the time to sort 1/99th of the data and send it back to the control computer, and the time for the control to read 1/2 the data. The "combination" is somewhere between the maximum and the sum of those times, probably close to the max.

My instinct is that for sending data over a network to be faster than sorting it (let alone just selecting the median) it needs to be a pretty damn fast network. Might be a better prospect if the network can be presumed to be instantaneous, for example if you have 100 cores with equal access to RAM containing the data.

Since network I/O is likely to be the bound, there might be some tricks you can play, at least for the data coming back to the control machine. For example, instead of sending "1,2,3,.. 100", perhaps a sorting machine could send a message meaning "100 values less than 101". The control machine could then perform a modified merge, in which it finds the least of all those top-of-a-range values, then tells all the sorting machines what it was, so that they can (a) tell the control machine how many values to "count" below that value, and (b) resume sending their sorted data from that point.

More generally, there's probably a clever challenge-response guessing game that the control machine can play with the 99 sorting machines.

This involves round-trips between the machines, though, which my simpler first version avoids. I don't really know how to blind-estimate their relative performance, and since the trade-offs are complex, I imagine there are much better solutions out there than anything I'll think of myself, assuming this is ever a real problem.

[*] available stack permitting - your choice of which part to do first is constrained if you don't have O(N) extra space. But if you do have enough extra space, you can take your pick, and if you don't have enough space you can at least use what you do have to cut some corners, by doing the small part first for the first few partitions.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong, why are you performing the 99-way merge on the data as it arrives only to discard later. Instead is it enough to keep the count the numbers as it arrives?

Comment: @SREEPRASADGOVINDANKUTTY: the repeating step is to discard the smallest value out of all 99 candidates, and increment the count. It's no use at all to merely keep a count of all incoming values without this 99-way merge step. If you don't compare them as they come in, you don't know that the value you're discarding is below the median.

Comment: But isn't there a small chance that any of these partitions contains only numbers higher than the median and therefore any lower partition it returns will be higher than the median, but as control does not know this it will discard them as being lower than the median and fail...?

Comment: @Gullydwarf: a multi-way merge only discards the smallest of the 99 values it has in hand, each of which is the smallest remaining value from one of the other machines. If one of the partitions is entirely greater than the median, then it will not become the least of those 99 values until after the median has gone past (at which point we're finished). So it will not be discarded.

Answer (score 52):

```
sort -g numbers | head -n 500000001 | tail -n 2 | dc -e "1 k ? ? + 2 / p"
```

Comment: LOL. Does that really work or will the OOM killer nuke it before it completes? (on any reasonable computer)

Comment: Should do. sort knows how to do an out-of-core sort, so it won't run out of memory.

Comment: @Zagfai I don't think it would take too long; a billion numbers is only 4 GB for 32-bit ints/floats, 8GB for 64-bit ints/doubles. Neither seems tremendously taxing.

Comment: Just tried on an Intel i5-4200M @3.1 GHz (4 cores). According to the `time` command applied to the whole pipeline, it took `real=36m24s` ("wall clock time"), `user=113m15s`  ("parallel time", all cores added). The longest command, far ahead the others, was `sort`, even if it threaded to my four cores at 100%. The RAM consumption was very acceptable.

Comment: 36 mins for this is huge, and the problem specifies there are 100 computers available, so any answer using only one computer should be disregarded

Comment: Then run in on 100 computers, so you can be 100 times more sure that the result is correct :)

Comment: @MorganTouvereyQuilling How fast does it go if you  use -S on sort to use more memory?

Comment: @Dici The "best" described by the OP seems subjective. 100 computers is overkill if even one of those computers has the capacity of a modern laptop. Considering the (unspec'd) network latency of transferring 4-8GB, this is probably still the better solution over any that uses multiple computers.

Comment: This "answer" is quite disrespectful. The OP clearly knows how to calculate a median. He's asking about how to distribute it. Now, if you think that distributing is not necessary, explain why in your answer. Simply posting an obvious one liner is unnecessarily snarky and fundamentally unhelpful.

Comment: @Sklivvz - this is a perfectly good answer. "Premature distribution" is unfortunately a big malaise in our industry.

Comment: @IsakSavo - I wouldn't expect any problems from the OOM killer since sort switches from an "in memory" algorithm to doing "disk based merge sort" once the data amount is above a certain size (which it would be in this case).

Comment: @Cd-MaN Your point about premature distribution would probably be valid if this answer would not take 34 minutes to run, whereas it could be achieved in just a few minutes (or seconds) with 100 computers. The amount of data to transfer is not that big, the network impact would not be terrible. I know I can write a Spark code as short as this answer and compute the result within 1 minute, but I did not do it because it is uninteresting. A good answer should provide a nice (and reasonably simple, because simpler is better) algorithm.

Comment: @Cd-MaN how do you know the "distribution" is premature? Certainly this answer shows nothing of the sort.

Comment: @DrPizza: Just tried with a buffer memory of 14 GiB, and visibly it doesn't change anything, at least on this type of sorting: real time is 38mn, 2 minutes more than without changing the default (sort was using <2 GiB on the first test). And the computer was a little less busy in this second try!

Comment: @MorganTouvereyQuilling lol sorry massive brain fail. I'll keep this as a monument to needing more tea.

Comment: @MorganTouvereyQuilling Huh, thanks for testing. Assuming you did have 14 GiB free (and it wasn't just thrashing) I'd have expected it to run a lot faster with more memory.

Comment: Yes, I had 14 GiB of entirely-free RAM and I don't have a swap.

Answer (score 29):

I hate to be the contrarian here, but I don't believe sorting is required, and I think any algorithm involving sorting a billion/100 numbers is going to be slow. Let's consider an algorithm on one computer.

1) Select 1000 values at random from the billion, and use them to get an idea of the distribution of the numbers, especially a range.

2) Instead of sorting the values, allocate them to buckets based on the distribution you just calculated. The number of buckets is chosen so that the computer can handle them efficiently, but should otherwise be as large as convenient. The bucket ranges should be so that approximately equal numbers of values go in each bucket (this isn't critical to the algorithm, but it helps efficiency. 100,000 buckets might be appropriate). Note the number of values in each bucket. This is an O(n) process.

3) Find out which bucket range the median lies. This can be done by simply examining the total numbers in each bucket.

4) Find the actual median by examining the values in that bucket. You can use a sort here if you like, since you are only sorting maybe 10,000 numbers. If the number of values in that bucket is large then you can use this algorithm again until you have a small enough number to sort.

This approach parallelizes trivially by dividing the values between the computers. Each computer reports the totals in each bucket to a 'control' computer which does step 3. For step 4 each computer sends the (sorted) values in the relevant bucket to the control computer (you can do both of those algorithms in parallel too, but it probably isn't worth it).

The total process is O(n), since both steps 3 and 4 are trivial, provided the number of buckets is large enough.

Comment: I think this is something in between of median of medians and quickselect algorithms.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm

Comment: In step 4, the buckets might not contain only 10,000. It might be the case that the distribution is skewed towards the middle, in which, it might contain, say, 80% of the data, which is still huge.

Comment: Edited to take account of that.

Comment: I like this approach.

Comment: The performance is not O(n) in this algorithm: you could have most numbers fall in the "median" bucket, and it could perform as badly as sorting everything.

Comment: +1 came up with the same idea of using buckets. I disagree with "any algorithm involving sorting a billion/100 numbers is going to be slow" though, see my answer below ;)

Comment: @DJClayworth I was considering a scale of 10^9 elements with 10^5 buckets. In a uniform distribution, there will be 10^4 elements in a bucket but in case of highly skewed distribution, the range of each bucket will be different to normalize the no. of elements in a bucket, how do we find these bucket ranges efficiently?

Comment: @WULF An excellent question. It's key to the algorithm, and step 1 addresses it. A sampling of the numbers to establish a distribution is the best I've come up with.

Comment: With this approach, were you envisioning storing the actual numbers in each bucket when building the *histogram*, or simply just a counter for the number of numbers that belong in each bucket, and then go through the data again to filter out the numbers that belong to the bucket in question?

Answer (score 12):

The *estimation* of order statistics like median and 99th percentile can be efficiently distributed with algorithms like [t-digest](https://github.com/tdunning/t-digest) or [Q-digest](http://www.inf.fu-berlin.de/lehre/WS11/Wireless/papers/AgrQdigest.pdf).

Using either algorithm, each node produces a digest, which represents the distribution of the values stored locally. The digests are collected at a single node, merged (effectively summing the distributions), and the median or any other percentile can then be looked up.

This approach is used by [elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-percentile-aggregation.html) and, presumably, [BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#aggfunctions) (going by the description of the QUANTILES function).

Answer (score 12):

One billion is actually quite a boring task for a modern computer. We're talking about 4 GB worth of 4 byte integers here ... 4 GB ... that's the RAM of some smartphones.

```
public class Median {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        int[] numbers = new int[1_000_000_000];

        System.out.println("created array after " +  (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + " ms");

        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            numbers[i] = rand.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("initialized array after " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + " ms");

        Arrays.sort(numbers);

        System.out.println("sorted array after " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + " ms");

        if (numbers.length % 2 == 1) {
            System.out.println("median = " + numbers[numbers.length / 2 - 1]);
        } else {
            int m1 = numbers[numbers.length / 2 - 1];
            int m2 = numbers[numbers.length / 2];
            double m = ((long) m1 + m2) / 2.0;
            System.out.println("median = " + new DecimalFormat("#.#").format(m));
        }
}
```

Output on my machine:

```
created array after 518 ms
initialized array after 10177 ms
sorted array after 102936 ms
median = 19196
```

So this completes on my machine within less than two minutes (1:43 of which 0:10 are to generate random numbers) using a single core and it's even doing a full sort. Nothing fancy really.

This surely is an interesting task for larger sets of numbers. I just want to make a point here: one billion is peanuts. So think twice before you start throwing complex solutions at surprisingly simple tasks ;)

Comment: this is what I said in my answer here :-)
http://stackoverflow.com/a/31819222/363437

Comment: @vidstige I honestly didn't read it, but you're right. my answer is certainly more hands-on though, which people seem to appreciate a bit more ;)

Comment: That's not the median though, the median is `(numbers[numbers.length / 2]+numbers[numbers.length / 2+1])/2` if `numbers.length` is even and `numbers[numbers.length / 2]` only if `numbers.length` is odd.

Comment: @Sklivvz correct, but it should not noticeable affect the time it takes to compute the median.

Comment: @Sklivvz you're of course right. I've just updated the median calculation. It doesn't change the rest of the answer though.

Comment: @Sklivvz That's actually the median though. Don't you forget the array index starting from 0?

Answer (score 5):

The median for this set of numbers

2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97

is 67.

The median for this set of numbers

2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89

is 40.

Assuming the question was about 1,000,000,000 integers(x) where 0 >= x <= 2,147,483,647 and that the OP was looking for (element(499,999,999) + element(500,000,000)) / 2 (if the numbers were sorted).  **Also assuming that all 100 computers were all equal.**

using my laptop and GigE...

What I found was that my laptop can sort 10,000,000 Int32's in 1.3 seconds.  So a rough estimate would be that a billion number sort would take 100 x 1.3 seconds(2 minutes 10 seconds) ;).

An estimate of a one-way file transfer of a 40MB file on a gigabit Ethernet is .32 seconds.  This means that the sorted results from all computers will be returned in approximately 32 seconds(computer 99 didn't get his file until 30 seconds after the start). From there it shouldn't take long to discard the lowest 499,999,998 numbers, add the next 2 and divide by 2.

Comment: Down voter comment?  It would help me understand how I can do better.

Comment: I'm not the down voter, but sorting a billion numbers won't take 100 times as long as sorting 10 million, because the worst-case complexity of sorting a list is O(n log n). Sorting is also orders of magnitude slower when you run out of memory and have to start sorting on disk.

Comment: I think you're on the right track; If the goal is quickest possible answer once, sorting on multiple machines might be a good idea. But if the goal is lowest average time, each machine doing it's own search makes more sense.

Comment: Assuming they have the same factor (which they probably don't due to memory issues) then `a*(1e7)log(1e7) = 1.3sec` => `a = 1.6e-9sec`  => `a*(1e9)log(1e9) ~ 167sec`, so your estimate wasn't that off.

Comment: Your estimations are way too rough. Firstly, some sorting algorithms go as o(n^2) in the worst case scenario (e.g. of the commonly used quicksort). Secondly, you have chosen a test dataset which is about the size of your L2 cache. This skews the results. Thirdly you (as many other answerers) assume "number" means "integer". It could mean float, double or decimal, which have very different performance characteristics.

Answer (score 5):

This might surprise people, but if the numbers are integers small enough to fit inside 32-bit (or smaller) - Just do a bucket sort! Only needs 16GB of ram for any number of 32-bit ints and runs in O(n), which should outperform any distributed systems for reasonable n, e.g. a billion.

Once you have the sorted list, it's trivial to pick out the median. In fact, you do not need to construct the sorted list, but only looking at the buckets should do it.

A simple implementation is shown below. Only works for 16-bit integers, but extension to 32-bit should be easy.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned short buckets[65536];
    int input, n=0, count=0, i=0;

    // calculate buckets
    memset(buckets, 0, sizeof(buckets));
    while (scanf("%d", &input) != EOF)
    {
        buckets[input & 0xffff]++;
        n++;
    }

    // find median 
    while (count <= n/2)
    {
        count += buckets[i++];
    }
    
    printf("median: %d\n", i-1);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Using a text file with a billion (10<sup>9</sup>) numbers and running with `time` like so

```
time ./median < billion
```

yields a running time on my machine 1m49.293s. Most of the running time is probably disk IO aswell.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question and it relies on assumptions. For example, you don't even know they are integers.

Comment: In what way does it not answer the question? And yes, my answer assumes the numbers are integers. I have tried to state my assumptions clearly.

Comment: You don't seem to state that having integers is an assumption, nor you address how to use the 100 computers the OP asks about. You can calculate the median on one node but that's not the "best" solution unless you show why. Also, radix sort is not o(n) if the number of digit varies, which in this case certainly does, according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort#Efficiency, it's o (n log n)

Comment: I start by saying "if the integers are small enough to fit inside a 32-bit *integer*"... Radix sort is O(n) for a constant word size _w_ as described in great clarity in the link you posted. Here I assume a constant word size of 32.

Comment: What you do with the 99 other computers is not relevant in this answer. You could stack them on top of each other to form a pyramid or burn them. Or just ignore them.

Answer (score 3):

Oddly enough, I think if you have enough computers, you're better off sorting than using `O(n)` median-finding algorithms.  (Unless your cores are very, very slow, though, I'd just use one and use an `O(n)` median-finding algorithm for merely 1e9 numbers; if you had 1e12, though, that might be less practical.)

Anyway, let's suppose we have more than log n cores to deal with this problem, and we don't care about power consumption, just getting the answer fast.  Let's further assume that this is a SMP machine with all the data already loaded in memory.  (Sun's 32-core machines are of this type, for instance.)

One thread chops the list up blindly into equal sized pieces and tells the other M threads to sort them.  Those threads diligently do so, in `(n/M) log (n/M)` time.  They then return not only their medians, but, say, their 25th and 75th percentiles as well (perverse worst cases are better if you choose slightly different numbers).  Now you have 4M ranges of data.  You then sort these ranges and work upwards through the list until you find a number such that, if you throw out *every* range that is smaller than or contains the number, you will have thrown out half your data.  That's your lower bound for the median.  Do the same for the upper bound.  This takes something like `M log M` time, and all cores have to wait for it, so it's really wasting `M^2 log M` potential time.  Now you have your single thread tell the others to toss all data outside the range (you should throw out about half on each pass) and repeat--this is a trivially fast operation since the data is already sorted.  You shouldn't have to repeat this more than `log(n/M)` times before it's faster to just grab the remaining data and use a standard `O(n)` median finder on it.

So, total complexity is something like `O((n/M) log (n/M) + M^2 log M log (n/M))`.  Thus, this is faster than `O(n)` median sort on one core if `M >> log(n/M)` and `M^3 log M < n`, which is true for the scenario you've described.

I think this is a *really bad idea* given how inefficient it is, but it is faster.

Comment: o (n/M log (n/M)) is, literally, o (n log n), because o(n/M log (n/M)) = 1/M o(n (log n - log M)) = o (n log n). You can't really compare it with o(n) like that, as the "o" basically means "proportional to for large very n with some unspecified constant". Unless you know these constants you can't compare, however for large enough N the constants are not dominant. For lower numbers all bets are off, o(1) can easily be slower than o(n!).

Comment: @Sklivvz - `n` and `M` are the variables that can scale arbitrarily, so one includes both.  In particular, I postulated that `M` > `log n`, meaning that if you care that it's `n log n` instead of just `n`, you have to care about `M` also.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done faster than the algorithm voted (n log n)

 - Order statistics distributed selection algorithm - O(n)
Simplify the problem to the original problem of    finding the kth number in an unsorted array.
 - Counting sort histogram O(n)
You have to assume some properties about the range of the numbers - can the range fit in the memory?
 - External merge sort - O(n log n) - described above
You basically sort the numbers on the first pass, then find the median on the second.
 
 - If anything is known about the distribution of the numbers other
   algorithms can be produced.

For more details and implementation see:
http://www.fusu.us/2013/07/median-in-large-set-across-1000-servers.html

Answer (score 2):

One computer is more than enough to solve the problem.

But let's assume that there are 100 computers. The only complex thing you should do is to sort the list. Split it to 100 parts, send one part to each computer, let them be sorted there, and merge parts after that.

Then take number from the middle of the sorted list (i.e. with index 5 000 000 000).

Comment: Anyway now my rep is pretty round :)

Comment: Merging is at best O(n), and you can find the median on a single core in O(n), so this seems to create a lot of extra work for no gain.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your data. The worst case scenario is that it's uniformly distributed numbers.

In this case you can find the median in O(N) time like in this example:

Suppose your numbers are 2,7,5,10,1,6,4,4,6,10,4,7,1,8,4,9,9,3,4,3 (range is 1-10).

We create 3 buckets: 1-3, 4-7, 8-10. Note that top and bottom have equal size.

We fill the buckets with the numbers, count how many fall in each, the max and the min

- low (5): 2,1,1,3,3, min 1, max 3
- middle (10): 7,5,6,4,4,6,4,7,4,4, min 4, max 7
- high (5): 10, 10, 8, 9, 9, min 8, max 10

The mean falls in the middle bucket, we disregard the rest

We create 3 buckets: 4, 5-6, 7. Low will start with a count of 5 and with a max of 3 and high with a min of 8 and a count of 5.

For each number we count how many fall in the low and high bucket, the max and the min, and keep the middle bucket.

- old low (5)
- low (5): 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, max 4
- middle (3): 5,6,6
- high (2): 7, 7, min 7
- old high (5)

Now we can calculate the median directly: we have a situation like this

```
old low    low          middle  high  old high
x x x x x  4 4 4 4 4 4   5 6 6  7 7   x x x x x
```

so the median is 4.5.

Assuming you know a little about the distribution, you can fine tune how to define the ranges to optimize speed. In any case, the performance should go with O(N), because 1 + 1/3 + 1/9... = 1.5

You need min and max because of edge cases (e.g. if the median is the average between the max of old low and the next element).

All of these operations can be parallelized, you can give 1/100 of the data to each computer and calculate the 3 buckets in each node, then distribute the bucket you keep. This again makes you use the network efficiently because each number is passed on average 1.5 times (so O(N)). You can even beat that if you only pass the minimal numbers among nodes (e.g. if node 1 has 100 numbers and node 2 has 150 numbers, then node 2 can give 25 numbers to node 1).

Unless you know more about the distribution, I doubt you can do better than O(N) here, because you actually need to count the elements at least once.

Comment: Isn't the real worse case (for your algorithm) when all the numbers are equal ? If I'm correct, none of your buckets will ever get filled apart from the middle one, with all elements. Thus, you will have to traverse all the elements each time, progressing exponentially fast to the middle of the interval. I believe it would be a `O(n log n)` in that case. Does it make sense ? By the way I like your idea

Comment: @Dici not really: firstly you can easily shortcut the "all the same" scenario because you know min and max. As I said in the answer, knowing the distribution could drive your bucketing choices; secondly, it would still take `o(n)+o(n/3)+o(n/9)+...` which is still `o(n)` and not `o(n log n)`.

Comment: On the other hand, there's probably a different worst case scenario, a U shaped distribution. I need to think a bit about it, formalize the worst case, but it could possibly do worse than `o(n)` in that case, with the naive partitioning.

Comment: Mmm yeah, the min and max would help to handle the "all same" case pretty easily

Answer (score 2):

An easier method is to have weighted numbers.

- Split the large set among computers
- Sort each set
- iterate through the small-set, and calculate weights to repeated elements
- merge each 2 sets into 1 (each is sorted already) updating weights
- keep merging sets until you get only one set
- iterate through this set accumulating weights until you reach OneBillion/2

Answer (score 1):

Split the 10^9 numbers, 10^7 to each computer ~ 80MB on each.  Each computer sorts its numbers.  Then computer 1 merge-sorts its own numbers with those from computer 2, computer 3 and 4, etc ... Then computer 1 writes half of the numbers back to 2, 3 to 4, etc.  Then 1 merge sorts the numbers from computers 1,2,3,4, writes them back.  And so on.  Depending on the size of RAM on the computers you may get away with not writing all the numbers back to the individual computers at each step, you might be able to accumulate the numbers on computer 1 for several steps, but you do the maths.

Oh, finally get the mean of the 500000000th and 500000001st values (but check there are enough 00s in there, I haven't).

EDIT: @Roman -- well if you can't believe it even it it's true then there's no point in my revealing the truth or falsehood of the proposition.  What I meant to state was that brute force sometimes beats smart in a race.  It took me about 15 seconds to devise an algorithm which I am confident that I can implement, which will work, and which will be adaptable to a wide range of sizes of inputs and numbers of computers, and tunable to the characteristics of the computers and networking arrangements.  If it takes you, or anyone else, say 15 minutes to devise a more sophisticated algorithm I have a 14m45s advantage to code up my solution and start it running.

But I freely admit this is all assertion, I haven't measured anything.

Comment: here we are just mergesorting all numbers. Can we do it in a better way using:- "we can find the median of two sorted lists in logn time. n is the length of each list."

Comment: @anony -- while you answer your own question, I'll have my solution coded up, tested and done.  I expect that there are better ways, but sometimes parallelising a simple way leaves me free to scratch my head on the really difficult problems.

Comment: have you really done it in **7** minutes? I can't believe that even if it's true. I did the similar task (it was a university assignment) and it took about 2 hours to implement and test all remoting stuff (I used java RMI).

Comment: I see what you're saying, but by the same token DrPizza has an even quicker-to-think-of solution, which is to sort all the data on a single node and ignore the other 99. None of us knows how expensive data transfer should be considered, so we're all just picking a compromise that sounds vaguely plausible. Your solution transfers all the data multiple times, so I'm a bit suspicious of it, but it's certainly a solution.

Comment: 'vaguely plausible' -- that's good enough for me @Steve !  Especially in response to a vaguely implausible question.

Answer (score 1):

This could be done on nodes using data that is not sorted across nodes (say from log files) in the following manner.

There is 1 parent node and 99 child nodes. The child nodes have two api calls:

- stats(): returns min, max and count
- compare(median_guess): returns count matching value, count less than value and count greater than value

The parent node calls stats() on all child nodes, noting the minimum and maximum of all nodes.

A binary search may now be conducted in the following way:

1. Bisect the minimum and maximum rounding down - this is the median 'guess'
2. If the greater than count is more than the less than count, set the minimum to the guess
3. If the greater than count is less than the less than count, set the maximum to the guess
4. If count is odd finish when minimum and maximum are equal
5. If count is even finish when maximum <= minimum + guess.match_count
   This could be done on nodes using unsorted data (say from log files) in the following manner.

There is 1 parent node and 99 child nodes. The child nodes have two api calls:

- stats(): returns min, max and count
- compare(median_guess): returns count matching value, count less than value and count greater than value

The parent node calls stats() on all child nodes, noting the minimum and maximum of all nodes.

A binary search may now be conducted in the following way:

1. Bisect the minimum and maximum rounding down - this is the median 'guess'
2. If the greater than count is more than the less than count, set the minimum to the guess
3. If the greater than count is less than the less than count, set the maximum to the guess
4. If count is odd finish when minimum and maximum are equal
5. If count is even finish when maximum <= minimum + guess.match_count

If the stats() and compare() could be pre-calculated with a O(N/Mlogn/M) sort, then a O(N/M) pre-calculation with a memory complexity of O(N) for the pre-calculation. Then you could do compare() in constant time, so the whole thing (including pre-calculation) would run in O(N/MlogN/M)+O(logN)

Let me know if I have made a mistake!

Comment: yeah i'd just do binary search. Would save network bandwidth only calling each computer a few times. Also each machine could have a "pivot" where it in place swaps numbers either side of the pivot to save time. (pivot would be the previous estimate of median, so next time, only have to go through all numbers on one side of the pivot)

Answer (score 0):

How about this:- each node can take 1Billion/100 numbers. At each node the elements can be sorted and median can be found. Find the median of medians. we can, by aggregating the counts of numbers less than median-of-median on all nodes find out x%:y% split which the median-of-medians makes. Now ask all nodes to delete elements less than the median of medians( taking example of 30%:70% split).30% numbers are deleted. 70% of 1Billion is 700million. Now all nodes which deleted less than 3million nodes can send those extra nodes back to a main computer. The main computer redistributes in such a way that now all nodes will have almost equal number of nodes(7million). Now that the problem is reduced to 700million numbers.... goes on until we have a smaller set which can be computed on one comp.

Comment: In essence we are always reducing the problem set by at least 30% and we are achieving a lot of parallel computing through this. Each node starts with 10million and reduces its data set by 30% in each iteration.

Comment: In the first iteration we look for 500Millionth number. In second iteration - if number of numbers deleted is 300million then we look for 200millionth number and so on...

Comment: This looks like it's on the right track, but you don't explain very clearly how to avoid throwing away the median by accident with your 30%/70% split.  Take the following counterexample: suppose your first 29% is all zeros, and all other blocks count up by 1000, and each set of blocks is one more than the last.  The 30th percentile median will throw away all of 29% of the data, and just under half of 61% of the data, which is 29+30% = 59% of the data.  Oops, we just threw out the true median!  So apparently you don't mean that, or at least you mean it more cleverly than I interpreted.

Answer (score 0):

Let's first work out how to find a median of n numbers on a single machine:
I am basically using partitioning strategy.

**Problem :selection(n,n/2) :** Find n/2 th number from least number.

You pick say middle element k and partition data into 2 sub arrays. the 1st contains all elements < k and 2nd contains all elements >= k.

if sizeof(1st sub-array) >= n/2, you know that this sub-array contains the median. You can then throw-off the 2nd sub-array. Solve this problem **selection(sizeof 1st sub-array,n/2)**.

In else case, throw off this 1st subarray and solve **selection(2nd subarray , n/2 - sizeof(1st subarray))**

Do it recursively.

**time complexity is** O(n) expected time.

Now if we have many machines, in each iteration, we have to process an array to split, we distribute the array into diff machines. Each machine processes their chunk of array and **sends back the summary to hub controlling machine i.e. size of 1st subarray and size of 2nd subarray.** The hub machines adds up summaries and decide which subarray (1st or 2nd) to process further and 2nd parameter of selection and sends it back to each machine.
and so on.

This algorithm can be implemented very neatly using map reduce?

How does it look?

Answer (score 0):

I think Steve Jessop's answer will be the fastest.

If the network data transfer **size** is the bottleneck, here is another approach.

```
Divide the numbers into 100 computers (10 MB each). 
Loop until we have one element in each list     
    Find the meadian in each of them with quickselect which is O(N) and we are processing in parallel. The lists will be partitioned at the end wrt median.
    Send the medians to a central computer and find the median of medians. Then send the median back to each computer. 
    For each computer, if the overall median that we just computed is smaller than its median, continue in the lower part of the list (it is already partitioned), and if larger in the upper part.
When we have one number in each list, send them to the central computer and find and return the median.
```

Comment: 32 MB each, you mean ?

Comment: What do you mean by continue in the lower part of the list?

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

in the beginning all 100 work to find the highest and the lowest number; each of the computer has his part of the database/file which it queries;

when the highest and lowest numbers are found, one computer reads the data, and distributes each number, evenly, to the rest of the 99; the numbers are distributed by equal intervals; (one may take from -100 million to 0, another - from 0 to 100 million, etc);

While receiving numbers, each of the 99 of the computers already sorts them;

Then, it's easy to find the median... See how many numbers has each computer, add all of them (the sum of how many numbers there are, not the numbers themselves), divide by 2; calculate in which computer is the number, and at which index;

:) voilla

P.S. Seems there's a lot of confusion here; the MEDIAN - is the NUMBER IN THE MIDDLE OF A SORTED LIST OF NUMBERS!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tournament tree method for finding the median.
We can create a tree with 1000 leave nodes such that each leaf node is an array.
We then conduct n/2 tournaments between the different arrays.The value on the root after the n/2 tournaments is the result.

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tournament-tree-and-binary-heap/

Answer (score 0):

If the numbers are not distinct, and only belong to a certain range, that is they are repeated, then a simple solution that comes to my mind is to distribute the numbers among 99 machines equally, and keep one machine as the master. Now every machine iterates over its given numbers, and stores the count of each number in a hash set. Each time the number gets repeated in the set of numbers allotted to that particular computer, it updates its count in the hash set.

All the machines then return their hash set to the master machine. The master machine combines the hash sets, summing the count of the same key found in a hash set. For example machine#1's hash set had an entry of ("1",7), and machine#2's hash set had an entry of ("1",9), so the master machine when combing the hash sets makes an entry of ("1", 16), and so on.

Once the hash sets have been merged, then just sort the keys, and now you can easily find the (n/2)th item and the (n+2/2)th item, from the sorted hash set.

This method won't be beneficial if the billion numbers are distinct.

Answer (score 0):

Well, suppose you know that the number of distinct integers is (say) 4 billion, then you can bucket them into 64k buckets and get a distributed count for each bucket from each machine in the cluster(100 computers). Combine all these counts. Now, find the bucket which has the median, and this time only ask for buckets for the 64k elements that would lie in your target bucket. This requires O(1) (specifically 2) queries over your "cluster". :D

Answer (score 0):

My penny worth, after all that has already been brought up by others:

Finding the median on a single machine is O(N): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm.

Sending N numbers to 100 machines is also O(N). So, in order to make using 100 machines interesting, either the communication must be relatively fast, or N is so large that a single machine cannot handle it while N/100 is doable, or we just want to consider the mathematical problem without bothering about datacommunication.

To cut things short I'll assume therefore that, within reasonable limits, we can send/distribute the numbers without affecting the efficiency analysis.

Consider then the following approach, where one machine is assigned to be the "master" for some general processing. This will be comparatively fast, so the "master" also participates in the common tasks that each machine performs.

1. Each machine receives N/100 of the numbers, computes its own median and sends that information to the master.
2. The master compiles a sorted list of all distinct medians and sends that back to each machine, defining an ordered sequence of buckets (on each machine the same), one for each median value (a single-value bucket) and one for each interval between adjacent medians. Of course there are also the lower-end and higher-end buckets for values below the lowest median and above the hightest.
3. Each machine computes how many numbers fall in each bucket and communicates that information back to the master.
4. The master determines which bucket contains the median, how many lower values (in total) fall below that bucket, and how many above.
5. If the selected bucket is a single-value bucket (one of the medians) orelse the selected bucket contains only 1 (N odd) or 2 (N even) values we're done. Otherwise we repeat the steps above with the following (obvious) modifications:
6. Only the numbers from the selected bucket are (re)distributed from the master to the 100 machines, and moreover
7. We're not going to compute (on each machine) the median, but the k-th value, where we take into account how many higher numbers have been discarded from the total, and how many lower numbers. Conceptually each machine has also its share of the discarded low/high numbers and takes that into account when computing the new median in the set that (conceptually) includes (its share of) the discarded numbers.

Time-complexity:

1. A little thinking will convince you that on each step the total number of values to analyse is reduced by a factor at least two (2 would be a rather sick case; you may expect a significantly better reduction). From this we get:
2. Assuming that finding the median (or k-th value), which is O(N), takes c*N time where the prefactor c does not vary too wildly with N so that we can take it as a constant for the moment, we'll get our final result in at most 2*c*N/100 time. Using 100 machines gives us, therefore, a speedup factor of 100/2 (at least).
3. As remarked initially: the time involved in communicating the numbers between the machines may make it more attractive to simply do everything on one machine. However, IF we go for the distributed approach, the total count of numbers to be communicated in all steps together will not exceed 2*N (N for the first time, <=N/2 the second time, <= half of that the third, and so on).

Answer (score -1):

1. Divide the 1 billion numbers into 100 machines. Each machine will have 10^7 numbers.
2. For each incoming number to a machine, store the number in a frequency map, 
   number -> count. Also store the min number in each machine.
3. Find median in each machine: starting from min number in each machine, sum the counts until median index is reached. The median in each machine, will be the approx. lesser and greater than 5*10^6 numbers.
4. Find median of all medians, which will be lesser and greater than approx. 50*10^7 numbers, which is the median of 1 billion numbers.

Now some optimization of 2nd step: Instead of storing in a frequency map, store the counts in a variable bit array. For example: Lets say starting from min number in a machine, these are frequency counts:

```
[min number] - 8 count
[min+1 number] - 7 count
[min+2 number] - 5 count
```

The above can be stored in bit array as:

```
[min number] - 10000000
[min+1 number] - 1000000
[min+2 number] - 10000
```

Note that altogether it will cost about 10^7 bits for each machine, since each machine only handles 10^7 numbers. 10^7bits = 1.25*10^6 bytes, which is 1.25MB

So with the above approach each machine will need 1.25MB of space to compute local median. And median of medians can be computed from those 100 local medians, resulting in median of 1 billion numbers.

Comment: What if the numbers are floats?

Answer (score -1):

I suggest a method to calculate approximately the Median. :) If these one billion numbers are in a randomly order, I think I can pick 1/100 or 1/10 of one billion number randomly, sort them with 100 machine, then pick the median of them. Or let's split billion numbers in 100 parts, let each machine pick 1/10 of each part randomly, calculate the median of them. After that we have 100 numbers and we can calculate the median of the 100 number easier. Just a suggestion, I'm not sure if it's mathematically correct. But I think you can show the result to a not-so-good-at-math manager.

Comment: It's obviously not correct, and I strongly recommend you to never assume your interviewer is a stupid pig you can trick

Comment: Haha ok, though it does not change the fact your answer is incorrect. It's very easy to prove it

Comment: OK, after reading some lecture about statistic, I think the idea picking up 1/100 or even 1/1000 randomly of one billion number and calculate their median is not so bad. It's just an approximate calculation.

Answer (score -3):

Steve Jessop's answer is wrong:

consider the following four groups:

{2, 4, 6, 8, 10}

{21, 21, 24, 26, 28}

{12, 14, 30, 32, 34}

{16, 18, 36, 38, 40}

The median is 21, which is contained in the second group.

The median of the four groups are 6, 24, 30, 36, The total median is 27.

So after the first loop, the four groups will become:

{6, 8, 10}

{24, 26, 28}

{12, 14, 30}

{16, 18, 36}

The 21 is already wrongly discarded.

This algorithm only support the case when there are two groups.