# Parallel computation of the median of a large array

Tags: parallel-processing, median

I got asked this question once and still haven't been able to figure it out:

You have an array of `N` integers, where `N` is large, say, a billion. You want to calculate the median value of this array. Assume you have `m+1` machines (`m` workers, one master) to distribute the job to. How would you go about doing this?

Since the median is a nonlinear operator, you can't just find the median in each machine and then take the median of those values.

Comment: What kind of communcation system do the m+1 machines have between them?

Comment: Possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571358/median-of-a-billion-numbers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on the [Parallel Computation Model](http://www.cs.rice.edu/~vs3/comp422/lecture-notes/comp422-lec20-s08-v1.pdf), algorithms could vary. (Note: the pdf linked to in previous sentence just contains some of the many possible ones).

Finding the median is a special case of finding the i<sup>th</sup> element. This problem is called 'selection problem', so you need to search the web for parallel selection.

Here is one paper (unfortunately, not free) which might be useful: [Parallel Selection Algorithms With Analysis on Clusters](http://www.computer.org/portal/web/csdl/doi/10.1109/ISPAN.1999.778969).

And google's first link for the query "Parallel Selection" gives: http://www.umiacs.umd.edu/research/EXPAR/papers/3494/node18.html which actually uses the median of medians for the general problem and not just median finding.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a highly parallelizable sort (like merge sort) and get the median from the result.

Answer (score 0):

Would sorting the array be overkill?  If not, then divide up the array and then merge the results together is my suggestion.

Comment: In some cases, it might not be overkill. If log(n) is not incredibly high (and here it's just 30), it not inconceivable that a parallel sort would be worth it - at least when sorting is more generally useful.