# PHP function to find the median of a column in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, median

I have a database, **db** and in it a table, **Table**.

It looks somewhat like:

```
id | val
--------
1  | 45
2  | 35
3  | 23
4  | 49
5  | 67
6  | 12
7  | 0
8  | 87
9  | 46
```

(This is just an example data set. Actual data set is huge. And I need to work in least time possible.)

I need to find the median of the column **val**. Actually I need a php function to be used multiple times.

A similar question does exist: [Simple way to calculate median with MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291152/simple-way-to-calculate-median-with-mysql)

I tried a few answers in this question, none of them worked for me. The accepted answer doesn't work since it used to work with an older version of SQL only.

PS: It should also work in the case of many duplicates.

Comment: If you just wanna do it in php, just pull out all the values, put into an array, sort the array, find median.

Comment: Won't that be slow? Sorting and then finding the mid value?

Comment: Well that depends on the data set for sure. I'm just going based on what's up there right now.

Comment: This was just an example, I actually have a huge data set. I'll modify the question. Thanks!

Comment: This is just a thought, but could you first count the size of data via sql. Then query for the data (sorted), but select 1/2 of the count rows, so you're at the mid point, then just last row of data?

Comment: Some thoughts on algorithms: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201292/on-algorithm-to-find-the-median-of-a-collection-of-numbers

Comment: And this one: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1914/to-find-the-median-of-an-unsorted-array

Answer (score -1, accepted):

just for fun i thought i try and do it all in MySQL, here's the [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/69100/1/0)

```
SELECT 
  CASE 
  WHEN MOD((select count(*) as count from t),2)=1 THEN
      (select val from
           (select @row:=@row+1 as row,val
            from t,(select @row:=0)r
            order by val)t1
       where t1.row = CEIL((select count(*) as count from t)/2)
      )
  ELSE
       ((select val from
           (select @row:=@row+1 as row,val
            from t,(select @row:=0)r
            order by val)t1
         where t1.row = (select count(*) as count from t)/2)+
        (select val from
           (select @row:=@row+1 as row,val
            from t,(select @row:=0)r
            order by val)t1
         where t1.row = ((select count(*) as count from t)/2)+1))/2 
  END AS median
```

Just replace occurences of `t` with your table name, don't change `t1`.
Also if the table has no rows, it'll return NULL as median.

This query can be further reduced to the below ([sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/69100/7/0))

```
SELECT @rowCount:=(select count(*) as count from t) AS rowcount,
      (select AVG(val) from
           (select @row:=@row+1 as row,val
            from t,(select @row:=0)r
            order by val)t1
       where t1.row IN (FLOOR((@rowCount+1)/2),
                         CEIL((@rowCount+1)/2)
                        )
      ) as Median
```

It'll return 2 columns, a `rowcount` column and a `median` column. I put the `rowcount` column there because i didn't want to count from t multiple times like previous query.

Comment: what does this return? I'm a newbie to MySQL, I'm having a hard time converting it to PHP.

Comment: Alright got it! Converted the result into an array and took the first element as my return output.

Comment: you might like the 2nd query better since it's about half the length of the first one.