# How to select the second smallest element from sorted list?

Tags: scala

How can I select the second smallest element after that a list has been sorted?

With this code I get an error and I do not understand why.

```
object find_the_median {
  val L = List(2,4,1,2,5,6,7,2)

  L(2)
  L.sorted(2) // FIXME returns an error
}
```

Comment: Just a note that you can find the median in O(n), if it matters: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201292/on-algorithm-to-find-the-median-of-a-collection-of-numbers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because `sorted` receives implicitly an `Ordering` argument, and when you do it like `L.sorted(2)` the typechecker thinks you want to pass `2` as an `Ordering`. So one way to do it in one line is:

```
L.sorted.apply(2)
```

or to avoid the `apply` pass the ordering explicitly:

```
L.sorted(implicitly[Ordering[Int]])(2)
```

which I admit is somewhat confussing so I think the best one is in two lines:

```
val sorted = L.sorted
sorted(2)
```

(You may also want to adhere to the Scala convention of naming variables with lowercase).

Comment: I think that the last version requires more memory than the previous two

Comment: There's no reason it requires more memory just because you name the result of L.sorted.

Comment: @Paul is right. Just because a new val is defined it doesn't mean it is allocating more memory. If I'm correct, in both cases, as the sorted array won't be used anymore, it will be collected by the garbage collector.