# After using Arrays.sort() how do I reverse array to its initial position?

Tags: java

I had to sort array to find its Median, but now I need to recover the initial value of array, put it as it was. Is that possible?

Comment: How about copy array before sort and after sort you can use your copy?

Comment: This. Any strategy for saving the original order and then sorting back to it would dwarf the time copying the array.

Comment: @MartynasKrupskis Please mark one of the answers as accepted.

Answer (score 6):

You can't do that. Sorting is irreversible. However, you could also add all elements of your original list to a new ArrayList and then sort that list.

```
List<String> original = ...;
List<String> copy = new ArrayList<>(original);
Collections.sort(copy);
```

---

*I would not worry about the footprint of the copy. It is a shallow copy, that means that the elements themselves are not copied, but only a new list is created with references to the elements contained in the original list. And that operation is quite fast. I would only worry if the list was very, very big.*

Comment: in this case what is the recommendation if the list was very very big?

Comment: @experimentunit1998X Well, either not sort it, or, if the sorting is really really important for you, then I would use something like a `TreeSet` or a similar structure.

Answer (score 3):

Using @McEmperors answer but with arrays

```
Object[] saved = Arrays.copyOf(old, old.length);
Array.sort(old);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to achieve what you want:

1. [copy the array before sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53509072/4265739)

   ```
   int[] unsorted = {2,3,1};
   int[] sorted = unsorted.clone();
   Arrays.sort(sorted);
   //find mean in sorted then proceed with unsorted
   ```
2. [create a custom sort function that retains a mapping between the positions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859261/get-the-indices-of-an-array-after-sorting)
3. [find the mean without sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33964676/find-the-median-of-an-unsorted-array-without-sorting)